# Apache url-rewriting fails when URL contains "index"

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, url-rewriting

All the pages of my website work with url rewriting, for example:

```
http://localhost/inventory/orga/organization/manage
```

But 2 urls are not working, and both contain "index" in the URL, so I suspect this is the cause:

```
http://localhost/inventory/index
http://localhost/inventory/index/home
```

These URL lead to a `404` not found.

The website is a PHP application. Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /inventory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

I've checked Apache configuration I can't find anything wrong. The DirectoryIndex is the default one for Ubuntu (`index.php`, `index.html`, ... but not just `index`).

Any idea why and how to solve this?

Comment: I don't see any problem here, I tested same code without any issue with index

Comment: Your application is likely to be returning the 404 as any files that don't exist are rewritten to your index.php unless there are other rewrite rules that you have not included

Comment: @Anigel so I shouldn't be having a 404. Anyway all the other pages work correctly, and Akam tested it too.

Comment: The rewrite rule is sending it to your application. Something in your application is returning the 404 not the rewrite rule

Comment: @Anigel ok I see what you mean, but I'm 100% sure there's no problem application side. I switched PC and reinstalled the system and now the problem has appeared. I'm using exactly the same code as all my other colleagues, and the app is working perfectly in production. I'm suspecting the Apache configuration (not the rewrite rules or the application itself).

Comment: Check apache config for any mention of "index" You could have another rewrite rule in there in places other than DirectoryIndex directive. (And remember to check any included conf as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options -MultiViews would stop /inventory/index from being mapped to index.php on-disk by mod_negotiation.

Since you use %{REQUEST_FILENAME} in per-directory mod_rewrite you're implicitly seeing the result of any module like mod_negotiation/mod_dir that may have mapped the URL to a filena,e.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because your app's base file IS INDEED an index.php, right ? Your .htaccess file says that when there's a real file with that name, then use that (which makes sense for image files, js, etc.)

I'm running something very similar to your and i don't have that problem. Have a look on my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

#When using the script within a subfolder, put this path here, like /mysubfolder/
RewriteBase /myprojectsfolder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What does happen when you delete your last .htaccess line ?

Comment: I'll try it at work tomorrow. But the thing is that's a setup that I've used for years, and that cause no problem for my colleagues (or in production). But I've switched to a fresh install of Ubuntu and I'm guessing Apache is treating "index" as the same as "index.php" so he's not applying the rewrite rules. But I don't know why! :S

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Maybe you now have a different version of Apache or a different config file (which is really realistic!). I would look for a backup of the old server.

Comment: It's not a server, it's my dev machine. And the old install is gone. Anyway it was a windows machine, so it doesn't matter.